# Does CyanogenMod 7.2 kernel support swap memory?

Tags: cyanogenmod, custom-roms, swap

My current kernel (whatever is built into stock Froyo 2.2 ROM for Verizon Motorola Droid X) does NOT support swap memory.

Does CyanogenMod 7.2 kernel support swap memory? Does that depend on device-specific build?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [cyanogenmod](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/) team feels that swap doesn't serve it's purpose on an Android device:

> This question is hotly debated, but you almost definitely do not need swap or compcache...

You can read all about it at the [Swap and Compcache - CyanogenMod Wiki](http://oldwiki.cyanogenmod.org/wiki/Swap_and_Compcache)!

---

**To answer you question directly**, by default the swap and Compcache schemes are disabled, but if you still feel the need to use them, above link provides you with a how-to.

So, yes, the CyanogenMod 7.2 supports swap and its usage needs to be activated.

The swap and Compcache schemes usage depends on the device and its support for it.

---

As a side note, the CyanogenMod 7.x is Gingerbread-based not Froyo, as can be read [here](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/blog/cyanogenmod-7-2):

> After 3 rounds of release candidates, and squashing a few more bugs in the stabilization branch of CyanogenMod 7, the newest stable iteration of the **Gingerbread-based** CM7 is now being released.

Comment: Swap is not suitable for Android smartphones/tablets as realistically speaking it could potentially wear and tear of the flash nand storage due to read/write (swapping in/out) to partition.

Comment: **Agree**, and it can be read on the link provided, that close to no gain comes from the swap or Compcache schemes usage!

Comment: @Zuul - my main problem is that (1) none of the apps I care about (e.g. stock browser) support the behavior described in CM Wiki linked - when the browser is killed by memory manager, it is next reloaded with empty page instead of whatever tabs I had open. Never mind keeping the page from reloading so that Google Reader does't lose the article I had open. (2) After playing some memory intensive games, it takes forever to re-launch my Zeam launcher. It's possible swap won't help; but I'm interested in trying. VERY helpful answer, thanks!

Comment: So we're stuck with apps taking 5 minutes to open every time you switch between them?  They should leave it up to the users to decide whether it's useful for them.  Android's intended behavior of killing apps and apps storing their state so they can be reloaded gracefully is wishful thinking, not reality.

Comment: Also that link is dead.  Any mirrors?

Comment: @endolith I've updated the link, thank you for the warning!

Comment: @Zuul: Thanks.  It seems CM7.2 doesn't support swap at all, though, and a different kernel needs to be installed.

Answer (score -1):

Short answer:

No. Kernel support is missing. You need to replace the kernel.

Longer answer - check answer from Zuul.