# Swap partition not working on Huawei U8160 running CyanogenMod 7.2

Tags: cyanogenmod, external-sd, mount, partitions, swap

I have a Huawei U8160 (also known as : Vodafone 858 Smart) which is running CyanogenMod 7.2 (which was released by MADTeam in 2/7/2012).

After updating to the 2/7/2012 update, I found an option to use swap partition instead of compcache (compressed cache), so I repartitioned my SD card to make a swap partition using [mini tool partition wizard](http://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html) which is 100 MB in size and primary (I had an Ext2 partition).  But after enabling the swap option the programs where slower, so I checked whether the swap partition was working or not.  I used the terminal emulator and typed "free" and the swap partition was all zeros.

So I wanted to know if I should mount it or do something else to make it work?

Comment: Swap partition has no place on smartphones, and induces a placebo in thinking everything is running faster when it has no purpose.

Comment: but many people say it's working on cyanogen mod

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24786/does-cyanogenmod-7-2-kernel-support-swap-memory?rq=1 Read that question that was answered before.

Comment: @t0mm13b that is not my question , I'm asking how to make it work right?

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to apply and use swap on your device, using a swap file or using a swap partition. This guide provides instructions for both of them.

## Disable Compcache

First step is to confirm the status or presence of the compressed cache, thus ensuring that it is disabled.

While CyanogenMod does not enable Compcache support on all devices, and by default if available it comes disabled, you can check the status by accessing:

```
    Settings » CyanogenMod settings » Performance settings » Compcache
```

If it doesn't show, your device doesn't support Compcache. If it show, disable it to use swap instead.

## Using swap (file or partition)

Swap can give more available memory than Compcache, but you need at least a class 6 SD card to prevent slow access times. You should also be aware that SD write wear is increased, so, the card will last less than usual would last.

### Using a swap file

This is the easiest way, you can have an app creating and managing the swap file for you:

Here's three recommended apps for this:

- [Swapper 2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lv.n3o.swapper2&hl=en)
- [Swapper](http://code.google.com/p/a-swapper/)
- [DroidSwap](http://www.androlib.com/android.application.com-droidheaven-droidswap-qBFw.aspx)

### Using a swap partition

You can manually create a swap partition, but for that to happen, you need to backup your SD card contents; format, and partition it.

The swap partition does bring better compatibility, when compared with swap files, but only concerning the connection of your phone as an USB mass storage device.

#### SD card partitioning

The method of reference if the use of [MiniTool Partition Wizard Home Edition](http://www.partitionwizard.com/download.html), compatible with Windows 2000/XP/Vista & Windows 7.

1. Download and install MiniTool Partition Wizard;
2. Remove the SD card from your device, insert into USB SD Card reader.
3. Windows should report a new drive and you should see the drive contents.
4. Delete old partitions on SD card:

   **Notes:**

   Operations are QUEUED, not instantly applied. So nothing is deleted and changed UNTIL you click "APPLY" and then confirm by clicking "OK".

   Confirm that you are selecting and flagging to delete the correct drive. Your SD card should be the smallest one present on your computer.

   Select it, with a right mouse click, select "Delete":

   [image: MiniTool - Screenshot 01]
5. Create FAT or FAT32 partition:

   Right mouse click over the SD card unallocated space, and click "create":

   - From "Create As", select: `PRIMARY`
   - From "File System", select:

     - For SD card bellow 2GB: `FAT`
     - For SD card above 2GB: `FAT32`
   - Under "Size and Location", at the right side, mouse left click and hold, then slide to the left to adjust the space for this partition.

   [image: MiniTool - Screenshot 02]
6. create ext2 or ext3 or swap partition:

   Right mouse click over the SD card unallocated space, and click "create":

   - From "Create As", select: `PRIMARY`
   - From "File System", select:

     - For App2SD: `ext2`
     - For swap: `Linux Swap`

   [image: MiniTool - Screenshot 03]
7. Apply changes

   Now that all has been created, you just need to apply and confirm the changes:

   On the top left, there's a button labeled "Apply", press it:

   [image: MiniTool - Screenshot 04]

   A confirmation popup should be presented, press "Yes":

   [image: MiniTool - Screenshot 05]

All done, your SD card can now return to your phone. If your current ROM is capable of using swap, it will detect and use it.

---

## Notes

Please read everything carefully before proceeding. As mentioned by t0mm13b in the comments to your question, this [subject as been covered](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/24795/16265), and the CyanogenMod team informs that this features are disabled by default due to potential issues:

> Swap and Compressed Cache (Compcache) are optional memory management systems. By default, these schemes are disabled due to potential issues with some configurations.

#### Credits to:

- [CyanogenMod Wiki - Swap and Compcache](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/Swap_and_Compcache)
- [XDA Developers Forum - SD card partitioning](http://forum.xda-developers.com/wiki/SD_card_partitioning)

Comment: actually that is what I did EXACTLY , now my question is after all of this it's not working ,what should I do?

Comment: @MohamedEssam As one can read from the CyanogenMod Wiki, if he doesn't use swap, is because there's no support for it. There is nothing to do, but wait for a new version that may already have support.

Comment: @MohamedEssam Nonetheless, recent devices don't need swap, there's more than enough memory to perform all tasks. If developers didn't found useful the usage of swap, why would we need it after all? They are the experts, and they do spend tons of hours testing things up before releasing them to the market.

Comment: my phone doesn't have enough RAM.so I need the swap partition.